# How to efficiently sort one array by another

Tags: java, arrays, sorting, performance

Suppose I have the following setup:

```
double[] vectorUsedForSorting = new double[] { 5.8,6.2,1.5,5.4 }
double[] vectorToBeSorted = new double[] {1.1,1.2,1.3,1.4}
```

I would like to sort `vectorToBeSorted` based on the natural numerical ordering of `vectorUsedForSorting`.

For example, the natural ordering would be `[1.5,5.4,5.8,6.2]` which corresponds to indices `[2,3,0,1]`, which would mean I want the output of the sorting function to be `[1.3,1.4,1.1,1.2]`.

How do I do this in the most absolute efficient/fast possible way? I am mostly concerned with time-complexity since I will be doing this for 1,000,000 length arrays.

A large bonus will be awarded to a fast/efficient answer.

Comment: A) write sort B) pass both arrays C) sort both simultaneously only based on values from first.

Comment: Have you changed your mind w.r.t. [the previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21608646/fastest-way-to-sort-an-array-by-a-separate-array-of-indices-indexes)? Now you really need sorting?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The simple solution:

```
class D implements Comparable<D> {
    double key;
    double value;

    @Override
    public int compareTo(D other) {
        return Double.compare(key, other.key);
    }
}

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        double[] vectorUsedForSorting = new double[] { 5.8,6.2,1.5,5.4 };
        double[] vectorToBeSorted = new double[] {1.1,1.2,1.3,1.4};

        D[] array = new D[vectorUsedForSorting.length];
        for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
            array[i] = new D();
            array[i].key = vectorUsedForSorting[i];
            array[i].value = vectorToBeSorted[i];
        }

        Arrays.sort(array);

        for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
            vectorToBeSorted[i] = array[i].value;
        }

        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(vectorToBeSorted));

    }
}
```

This does require a little extra memory for the auxiliary array and objects, but should come close to optimal in execution time.

Comment: This algorithm is O(nlogn) since Arrays.sort() is O(nlogn). This is probably as good as it gets.

Comment: This gives 560 milliseconds for 1 million datapoints. Good enough.

Answer (score 2):

Perform merge-sort on the first table, and do the same operations on the second table at the same time. Complexity nlogn guaranteed

Comment: Hmm I'm not sure, can you write a method? I will award bonus.

Comment: Yeah it's fine. I will write something and if it's faster than meriton I will aware you the answer. Cheers.